# Kendo grid doesn't update ID after create

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My grid has all crud operations working, the only problem is that after I save a new record, the grid does not update to the new ID from the controller. I have verified that the ID is being sent back from the controller with the model, but the grid does not update. Therefore any subsequent changes to the same record without a page refresh create a new record.

Controller:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AddHoleToJob([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PlannedHolesVM viewModel)
        {
            _jobInfoService.AddHole(viewModel);
            return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Cshtml:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<PlannedHolesVM>()
.Name("PlannedHolesKendoGrid")
.Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("HoleDetails"))
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Bound(m => m.ID);
    c.Bound(m => m.HoleSectionLookupName);
    c.Bound(m => m.HoleSectionTypeLookupHoleSectionType);
    c.Bound(m => m.HoleSize);
    c.Command(command =>
    {
        command.Edit();
        command.Destroy();
    });
})
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add Hole"))
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(c => c.ID);
        model.Field(c => c.JobID);
        model.Field(c => c.JobID).DefaultValue(ViewBag.Jobid);
        model.Field(c => c.HoleSectionID);
        model.Field(c => c.HoleSectionTypeID);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("PlannedHolesGridData", "JobRecord", new { jobid = ViewBag.Jobid }))
    .Destroy(delete => delete.Action("DeleteHoleFromJob", "JobRecord"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("AddHoleToJob", "JobRecord"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("AddHoleToJob", "JobRecord"))
    )
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.DataBound("dataBound");
        e.Save("refreshOnSave");
    })
)
```

How do I make the grid update the new ID without calling read and going back to the database?

Comment: You have specified the same URL for both `Create` and `Update` methods.

Comment: Yes this is on purpose. They both call the save method in a modified version of automapper/entity framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through several similar posts  and finding a Telerik post that explained that the schema is predefined when using razor and expects data that looks like:

```
{
    "Data": [{
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai8",
        "UnitPrice": 18.00,
        "UnitsInStock": 39,
        "Discontinued": false
    }, {
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 19.00,
        "UnitsInStock": 17,
        "Discontinued": false
    }],
    "Total": 2,
    "AggregateResults": null,
    "Errors": null
}
```

I was able to modify my controller to return the Json in the way that was expected and the grid does update the ID. Here's the controller code:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult AddHoleToJob([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, PlannedHolesVM viewModel)
        {
            _jobInfoService.AddHole(viewModel);
            return Json(new { Data = viewModel });
        }
```

### Notice the capital 'D'.

Comment: Replying to something very old, but I just had the same issue and tried the same solution, which worked. This puzzles me though, as I have usually done the same as you have done in your original post. Until one time it didn't. To be honest I have no idea why or what happened, but the solution here worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Check the database, to see if **ID** is set as **auto incerment** , remove Auto increment from id field

Comment: It is set to auto-increment. Otherwise when I insert a value as zero, the ID will not be auto-created by entity framework. This new value is being returned, but not reflected in the grid. Are you saying that Kendo grid will not work with auto-incremented fields?